# Solve: should not return empty solutions

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the equation 
$$\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}=0$$
which should have a solution $x=0$. This is because 
$$\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}=\frac{x^2}{x(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})}=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
However, using Solve, Mathematica returns empty solution. Is there any way to let the Mathematica return the correct result? (The code is attached here.)

```
Solve[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/x == 0, x]
```

Comment: Disable the automatic verifier: `In[55]:= Solve[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/x == 0, x, 
 VerifySolutions -> False]

Out[55]= {{x -> 0}}` In general, such solutions should be tested using e.g. `Limit`.

Comment: @ DanielLichtblau, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For `(-1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/x` to be zero, its numerator must be zero, so

```
Solve[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2]) == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 0}} *)
```

But, in that case, we have `0/0` for the full formula, so `x->0` is not a solution. There are no solutions.